# Jmeter - Missing Samples in load test?

Tags: apache, soap, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a CSV Data Config which is looking up a number list. This number list goes from 1 to 4050.

I have 4050 XML files which are to be transmitted via SOAP-XML. Named 1.xml, 2.xml etc..

As you can see my intention is that my thread iterates through the xml files, sending them in order of 1,2,3,...

It does do this however when my load test has finished, the number of samples that has been sent is 3278 (this is seen via View Results in Table)

I have triple checked my CSV file has 4050 numbers, I have also checked that I actually have 4050 xml files. Everything is there.

Does anyone have any idea why I am missing 772 samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you :

- set Thread Group to loop forever and csv dataset to stop at end of file ?
- or set thread group to iterate as much as you have files if you have 1 thread
- or set thread group to iterate as much as you have file divided by number of threads  if you have more than 1 thread

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is much appreciated.

I have a single thread operating, the CSV Data config set to "Stop thread on EOF". And the thread group is set to Loop Forever.

I am not sure I understand your second two points, sorry.

Comment: verify option stop on error in thread group, it should be continue on error, also check jmeter.log for errors